# Android Studio throws "No signature of method" error, pointing to build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I got the following error when compiling my code in Android Studio:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

`> No signature of method: build_16swdi705s6eau9c2h85w6rs5.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_16swdi705s6eau9c2h85w6rs5$_run_closure1) values: [build_16swdi705s6eau9c2h85w6rs5$_run_closure1@34d7c56f]`

The error points me to this section of the build.gradle:app file (specifically, the line with `android` `{`

`android { compileSdk version 31`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.facedetection"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

What does this error message mean, and what can I change to fix the issue?

Comment: Please add build.gradle:app completely

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your signing configs are correct, which looks like this-

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

and then set the compileSdkVersion to 30 and targetSdkVersion to 30.